# Make replaced fragment visible while transition ongoing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-transitions, android-architecture-navigation

Im using Navigation Architecture Component and i got my shared element transition between two fragments working fine. First fragment contains recyclerview and second one is a "details" of recyclerview item. The problem is that i need to keep first fragment visible while transition in progress.

How do i make transition like that ? Is there any option to achieve this with Navigation Architecture Component ? If no, what i need to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know is it really possible with Navigation. 
But its really possible with basic FragmentTransaction

```
 fragmentManager!!
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true) // setAllowOptimization before 26.1.0
                    .addSharedElement(view.imageIV, "fragment_news_iv")
                    .addSharedElement(view.title, "fragment_news_title_tv")
                    .addSharedElement(view.date, "fragment_news_date_tv")
                    .addSharedElement(view.container, "fragment_news_scrollView")
                    .addSharedElement(view.description, "fragment_news_description_tv")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .setCustomAnimations(
                        android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out,
                        android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out
                    )
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .add(
                        R.id.main_host_fragment,
                        NewsDetailsFragment(),
                        NewsDetailsFragment::class.java.simpleName
                    ).addToBackStack(null)
                    .hide(this@MainFragment)
                    .commit()
```

Here is part of code which is doing transaction.

U can set custom animations like fade_in, fade_out with long duration(1000ms)

```
.setCustomAnimations(
                        android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out,
                        android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out
                    )
```

And set sharedEnterTransition in detailsFragment with duration 200

```
  val trans = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
    trans.apply {
        duration = 200
        enterTransition = trans
    }

    sharedElementEnterTransition = trans
```

So its obvious that first fragment will still be visible while transaction will be in progress. This is kinda workaround solution, but works)

Answer (score 1):

The way exit transitions work is by adding the target views to a [ViewOverlay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOverlay) that is added to the entering fragment. This means that, once the fragment is replaced, only the entering fragment exists and all the transitions applied to views that are exiting are actually happening on views that have been added to the entering fragment's [ViewOverlay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOverlay).

The reason why your exiting fragment doesn't stay visible is because you don't have an exit transition which means that no views are added to the `ViewOverlay` of the entering fragment.

Each view that is targeted in the exit transition is added to the `ViewOverlay` which sits on top of the entering fragments view hierarchy. So having the exiting fragment just sit there whilst the transition happens is not possible because once you target any views of the exiting fragment it will cause them to be on top of the view hierarchy, thus hiding all the other views (including the shared element).

Your best bet is probably to use a [Fade](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/Fade) transition as the exit transition and this way you can create a cross fade between the fragments

Comment: I understand. But hard to tell the customer that I will use a fade instead of move transition). So i need to find different way for this feature.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a limitation of fragment transitions :/ You can still keep the shared element transition as you want but to my knowledge keeping the other elements of the fragment in place without any kind of [Visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/Visibility) transition is not possible.

Comment: i just fount a solution. This is really possible. I will post answer, so u can check how to achieve this.